# GitHub - How can i import files in order to view them

Tags: git, github

I'm a Java student. My teacher shared some files on gitHub and I would like to view them. How do I get those files into my Git account in order to (at least)view them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[git](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1) clone git://github.com/Your_Teacher_GitHub_Account

Answer (score 0):

Read about [setting up git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) and about [creating and using repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo) at [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/). I know that you don't need to set up a repo, but it will also explain how to download (or clone in git speak) and upload (push).